# Android: can't load a photo saved from camera

Tags: android, android-intent, camera, uri

I have a problem with taking a photo with the camera and showing it on an Activity. Basically the photo doesn't get loaded and BitmapFactory.decodeStream return null. strangely enough, if I wait in debug for some time, it gets loaded. although this behavior is not consistent. I'm also using the `com.isseiaoki.simplecropview.CropImageView` to crop the image which handles the bitmap decoding. This is the relevant code:

Activity:

```
private final String DATA_PATH = "/mnt/sdcard/ocr/";
private void init() {
            if (getIntent().getIntExtra(KEY_SHOULD_OPEN, 0) == CAMERA) {
                tryOpenCamera();
            } else {
                openGallery();
            }

            createImageFile();
        }

    public void createImageFile(){
            File photo;
            try
            {
                // place where to store camera taken picture
                photo = createTemporaryFile("picture", ".jpg");
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                showGenericErrorDialog();
                photo = null;
            }
            if(photo != null){

                photoUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".provider", photo);
            }
        }


        private File createTemporaryFile(String part, String ext) throws Exception
        {
            File tempDir=new File(DATA_PATH);

            if(!tempDir.exists())
            {
                tempDir.mkdirs();
            }
            return File.createTempFile(part, ext, tempDir);
        }

    private void openCamera() {
            Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoUri);
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
        }

    @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            if (requestCode == REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                updateImageUI(photoUri);
            } 
        }

    private void updateImageUI(Uri uri) {
            getBinding().cropImageView.startLoad(
                    uri,
                    new LoadCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess() {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError() {
                            showGenericErrorDialog();
                        }
                    });
        }
```

crop library-related code:

```
public void startLoad(Uri sourceUri, LoadCallback callback) {
        mLoadCallback = callback;
        mSourceUri = sourceUri;
        if (sourceUri == null) {
            postErrorOnMainThread(mLoadCallback);
            throw new IllegalStateException("Source Uri must not be null.");
        }
        mExecutor.submit(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mIsLoading = true;
                mExifRotation = Utils.getExifOrientation(getContext(), mSourceUri);
                int maxSize = Utils.getMaxSize();
                int requestSize = Math.max(mViewWidth, mViewHeight);
                if (requestSize == 0) requestSize = maxSize;
                try {
                    final Bitmap sampledBitmap = Utils.decodeSampledBitmapFromUri(getContext(),
                            mSourceUri,
                            requestSize);
                    mInputImageWidth = Utils.sInputImageWidth;
                    mInputImageHeight = Utils.sInputImageHeight;
                    mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            mAngle = mExifRotation;
                            setImageBitmap(sampledBitmap);
                            if (mLoadCallback != null) mLoadCallback.onSuccess();
                            mIsLoading = false;
                        }
                    });
                } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
                    Logger.e("OOM Error: " + e.getMessage(), e);
                    postErrorOnMainThread(mLoadCallback);
                    mIsLoading = false;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Logger.e("An unexpected error has occurred: " + e.getMessage(), e);
                    postErrorOnMainThread(mLoadCallback);
                    mIsLoading = false;
                }
            }
        });
    }

public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromUri(Context context, Uri sourceUri, int requestSize) {
        InputStream is = null;
        try {
            is = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(sourceUri);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inSampleSize = Utils.calculateInSampleSize(context, sourceUri, requestSize);
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is, null, options);
    }
```

Manifest:

```
<provider
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
        </provider>
```

note that the URI looks something like this: `content://my.package.provider/%2Fmnt%2Fsdcard%2F/ocr/picture9052876345621346933.jpg`and I'm testing this on a Samsung Galaxy S7 with Android 8

EDIT: as of now, the problem is there only with the S7, other devices work correctly

any idea why this is happening and how to avoid it?

Comment: `photo = createTemporaryFile("picture", ".jpg");` You should not create that file already. The camera app will create the file. If the user cancels the operation you will have an empty file. The only thing you need is a File instance with the right path.

Comment: Please have a look at: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider

Comment: @blackapps I tried just doing `new File(DATA_PATH)` but the problem I still there.

I also want to point out that I tried other devices and this does not happen

Comment: `private final String DATA_PATH = "/mnt/sdcard/ocr/";` You cannot use such a path if you use FileProvider. A bad hard coded path it is.

Comment: @blackapps I tried using the code from the developers website: `File imagePath = new File(getFilesDir(), "images");
        File newFile = new File(imagePath, "default_image.jpg");
        photoUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".provider", newFile);` but I'm given the following exception: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains /data/data/my.package/files/images/default_image.jpg`

Comment: Whithout the provider_paths.xml file we cannot help you. Please put that code in your post. Code is awfull to read in comments.

Comment: `if(!tempDir.exists())
            {
                tempDir.mkdirs();
            }` Didnt i ask you lately to check the return value  of mkdirs()?

Comment: `tempDir.mkdirs(); ` doesn't even get's excuted as they already exist

Comment: That does not matter. If the code calls mkdirs() it should check te return value. A next time it will bite you if you dont.